# Logstash/ElasticSearch: guesses wrong for datatype for field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

The log files I'm trying to import into Logstash contain a field that sometimes looks like a date/time and sometimes does not.  Unfortunately, the first occurrence looked like a date/time and someone (logstash or elasticsearch) decided to define the field as a date/time.  When trying to import a later log record, Elasticsearch has an exception:

```
Failed to execute [index ...]  
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Failed to parse [@fields.field99]  
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.AbstractFieldMapper.parse(AbstractFieldMapper.java:320)  
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeValue(ObjectMapper.java:587)  
...  
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "empty"  
at org.elasticsearch.common.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseMillis(DateTimeFormatter.java:747)  
...
```

**Question**: How do I tell logstash/elasticsearch to not define this field as a date/time?  I would like all the fields from my log (except the one explicit timestamp field) to be defined as just text.

**Question**: it appears that logstash gives up trying to import records from the log file after seeing this one that elasticsearch throws an exception on.  How can I tell logstash to ignore this exception and keep trying to import the other records from the log file?

Comment: That's it! Maybe you can add your answer as a real answer instead of within the question itself, it's worth it.

Comment: stackoverflow would not let me answer my own question so soon after asking it since I'm a noob with a bad reputation  :D

Comment: I was able to move the answer to a proper answer below after waiting the required amount of time for answering my own question.

Comment: You're not a noob anymore, I upvoted both your question and answer ;)

Answer (score 9):

I found the answer to my first question myself.

Before adding data through Logstash, I had to set the defaults for Elasticsearch to treat the field as "string" instead of "date".

I did this by creating a defaults.js file like this:

```
{  
    "template": "logstash-*",  
    "mappings": {  
        `"_default_"`: {  
            "dynamic_templates": [{  
                "fields_template": {  
                    "mapping": { "type": "string" },  
                    "path_match": "@fields.*"  
                }  
            }]  
        }  
    }  
}
```

and telling Elasticsearch to use it before adding any data through Logstash:

curl -XPUT `'http://localhost:9200/_template/template_logstash/'` -d @defaults_for_elasticsearch.js

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Just to elaborate a little: you used the [put index template api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-templates/) to submit an index template. Why? Because logstash creates multiple indexes, usually one per day. All indexes that match the pattern will get the specified mapping. Also, you used the [`_default_`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/dynamic-mapping/) mapping so that all the types will get the specifed mapping. Within the mapping, you used a [dynamic template](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/root-object-type/) ;)